# How can I page through a MongoDB collection, where the sort is based on an integer property?

Tags: mongodb

Given documents such as:

```
{"points": 5},
{"points": 3},
{"points": 5},
{"points": 1}
```

I'd like to query (for example) for 2 documents at a time, and then query for the next 2 documents, sorting the entire thing by `points`. So, the results would be:

Query 1: `{"points": 5}, {"points": 5}`

Query 2: `{"points": 3}, {"points": 1}`

I've tried creating an index on `points` as well as a compound index on `points` and `_id` in an attempt to be able to query for all documents with an index "greater then" the last _id, or a concatenation of both values, etc. Nothing I'm trying is working. This seems trivial and I would bet I'm missing something with the indexes that will help me get this working.

Answer (score 3):

You can query your data in this way

```
 > db.example.find().skip(0).limit(2).sort({"points":-1})
     { "_id" : ObjectId("559583bcb3a5b29213f845eb"), "points" : 5 }
     { "_id" : ObjectId("559583d1b3a5b29213f845ed"), "points" : 5 }
 > db.example.find().skip(2).limit(2).sort({"points":-1})
     { "_id" : ObjectId("559583cab3a5b29213f845ec"), "points" : 3 }
     { "_id" : ObjectId("559583d5b3a5b29213f845ee"), "points" : 1 }
```

Edit:

```
> db.example.find().sort({"points":-1});
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5595923e66c8f5eb6958fd0c"), "points" : 12 }
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5595923966c8f5eb6958fd0b"), "points" : 11 }
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5595920066c8f5eb6958fd0a"), "points" : 10 }
  { "_id" : ObjectId("559591f766c8f5eb6958fd09"), "points" : 9 }
  { "_id" : ObjectId("559591a566c8f5eb6958fd08"), "points" : 8 }
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5595918f66c8f5eb6958fd07"), "points" : 7 }
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5595916d66c8f5eb6958fd06"), "points" : 6 }
  { "_id" : ObjectId("559583bcb3a5b29213f845eb"), "points" : 5 }
  { "_id" : ObjectId("559583d1b3a5b29213f845ed"), "points" : 5 }
  { "_id" : ObjectId("559583cab3a5b29213f845ec"), "points" : 3 }
  { "_id" : ObjectId("559583d5b3a5b29213f845ee"), "points" : 1 }
> db.example.find().skip(2).limit(2).sort({"points":-1});
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5595920066c8f5eb6958fd0a"), "points" : 10 }
  { "_id" : ObjectId("559591f766c8f5eb6958fd09"), "points" : 9 }
> db.example.insert({"points":14});
  WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.example.insert({"points":15});
  WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.example.find().skip(4).limit(2).sort({"points":-1});
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5595920066c8f5eb6958fd0a"), "points" : 10 }
  { "_id" : ObjectId("559591f766c8f5eb6958fd09"), "points" : 9 }
```

Edit 2:

Maybe this solution might work. In this solution you would use range to search for points that are lower than your last retrieved point. However, the problem is if you have more points with value 6 that are not displayed. In this case, it would be skipped, so you might combine this approach with some application logic to solve the issue:

```
> db.example.find({points:{$lt:6}}).limit(2).sort({"points":-1});
```

Hope this helps.
Zoran

Comment: Thanks Zoran. `skip` may have to work if I can't find an alternative. What I really need is to give me the next X records *after* the last record that was retrieved. This way we're always giving the next set of results regardless of new data that has appeared in the collection.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your need. What I suggested would provide you a simple pagination. You could query 2 records at the time sorted by points. If you need new records that came into the collection after your last retrieved record, then you should use query {'_id'> last_id}, but that means you might miss some older lower points that you didn't read yet.

Comment: Any new records that are created in between requests would throw off the results, I.e. I would get the same records in query 2 that I got in query 1 if 2 records were created in the meantime with greater points.

Comment: Please check my edits. It works as you described in previous comment. Maybe I didn't understand your idea well, though.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your last comment. You actually, don't want that to happen?

Comment: I added new edit with range approach which you might consider.

Comment: Thanks for the info Zoran! I think I will still have a problem where, as you've pointed out, points with the same value will be skipped, which is a problem for my application. In the first edit, you can see that `10,9` is returned both times, even when the skip increases. I think ultimately I will need to use a compound index, but that's a stab in the dark...

Comment: One additional idea came to my mind. It is in addition to edit 2 with range. You might combine this with $nin. For example, if your last query returned two points 5, and you have another point 5 that is still to be returned in next query, your next query would search for points that are less than last point+1, and in $nin part you will search for ids which are not already returned. This still could have some problems, but I'm not sure if you will be able to find an ideal solution for the problem you have.

Comment: That's a very clever idea! I may play with that. Thanks Zoran.